# How do I calculate $\left \| \vec{v}-\vec{u} \right \|_2$ for $\vec{u}\in U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U=\lambda ((1, 0, 1, 0)^T,(1, 1, 0, 1)^T,(1, -1, 1; 0)^T)$ 
Is a subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^4$. Determine for  $\vec{v} = (1, 1, 1, 1)^T$ the vector  $ \vec{u}\in U $ with minimal  $\left \| \vec{v}-\vec{u} \right \|_2 $.
 $\vec{u}= \left (\vec{v} · \vec{b_1}  \right )\vec{b_1} + \left (\vec{v} · \vec{b_2}  \right )\vec{b_2}+\left (\vec{v} · \vec{b_3}  \right )\vec{b_3}$

Comment: What does your $\lambda$ notation mean?

Comment: A bit cryptic for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, my question is how to find $b_1$ and so on, I'm not sure about that notation, i think it's not important